# Does the XBee ANSI C library work with the STM32F4 family?

Tags: xbee, stm32f4discovery

I am trying to use the STM32F4 family with XBee, but how can I send XBee API packets from one module to other via STM32F4?

Answer (score 0):

That isn't one of the platforms supported by the [XBee ANSI C Host Library](https://github.com/tomlogic/xbee_ansic_library), but an experienced embedded developer should be able to port that library over.  It was designed to target embedded platforms down to an 8-bit Freescale with 32K of flash an 2K of RAM.